# Error when including functions with require/include to a file containing "use" (doesn't find the functions I include with "use")

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I use the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin to create Wordpress custom fields.
As a complement I am starting to use an ACF extension that makes it easier for me to create the fields directly in code.
https://github.com/vinkla/extended-acf

As you will see in the documentation I need to use multiple "use" to use it:

```
use Extended\ACF\Fields\Image;
use Extended\ACF\Fields\Gallery;
use Extended\ACF\Fields\Editor;
use Extended\ACF\Fields\DatePicker;
```

As I want to use it in multiple files and I don't want to be constantly writing all the "use" in each one of them, I tried to add them all in a single file and do a "require" in the rest (so with one line in each file I already have them imported).

The problem is that it doesn't work.

Any idea of the error or a way to easily access the extension from all the files?

Thanks a lot.

I have checked that the file is well linked, but I don't care about the "use" and it doesn't recognise the extension functions.